# "乗せる" vs "乗っける"

Tags: words, nuances

Good afternoon all,

I was wondering when someone gives someone a ride (bicycle, car, etc), what's the difference in nuance between using the verb "乗せる" and the verb "乗っける"?

For example, I was wondering what's the difference in nuance/usage between these two sentences:

1. でもその、自転車に乗せてくれた子に感謝しなくちゃね。
2. でもその、自転車に乗っけてくれた子に感謝しなくちゃね。

And these two sentences:

1. 入試の日に自転車に乗せてくれた子。
2. 入試の日に自転車に乗っけてくれた子。

Comment: Probably, 乗っける derives from 乗る +つける...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`乗っける` is a colloquial and mascline (rough) way of saying `乗せる`. In formal occasions, you should not use `乗っける`.

Comment: Btw does it suggest that "入試の日に自転車に乗っけてくれた子" is said by a guy?

Comment: @Pacerier It may suggest that it is a male or a female who use rough (boyish) words.

Comment: Btw I was wondering instead of "boyish", can it also be "casual" for example in this example a child used it while talking within the family: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ZiI5c9BzWoI#t=35s

Answer (score 3):

乗っかる･乗っける are Kanto dialectal versions of 乗る･乗せる which have made it into the modern Tokyo dialect as colloquialisms.